# Download Azure Security Recommendations via Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am using Azure CLI (az advisor recommendation list) to download all recommendations for my subscriptions. What I've noticed is that it works perfectly ok for all recommendations except from security recommendations. For the security recommendations, I always get:

```
"shortDescription": {
      "problem": "Improve the security of your Azure resources",
      "solution": "Follow Security Center recommendations"
    },
```

even though on Azure those recommendations have concrete problem/solution (like *Enable Network Security Groups on subnets*)
I assume, I need to use another command to get the concrete security recommendation, however I cannot find anything in the documentation. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [az security task list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/security/task?view=azure-cli-latest#az-security-task-list)

Also, if you want to achieve the same using powershell, please use the following ASC powershell modules. A link for sample from github is provided.

ASC Powershell Module :-  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Security/0.2.0-preview

ASC Powershell Reference :- https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/preview/src/ResourceManager/Security/Commands.Security/help/AzureRM.Security.md

ASC sample :- https://github.com/Microsoft/Azure-Security-Center/blob/master/quickstarts/ASC-Samples.ps1

Please check the blog on how to install the module. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/germanageability/2018/09/04/installing-and-testing-the-new-azure-security-center-preview-cmdlets/

Get-AzureRmSecurityTask will give you details of the types of recommendation suggested for each resource where the policy is applied.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to connect security recommendations from Advisor with security tasks ?

Comment: This thread might help you with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317621/is-it-possible-to-access-azure-security-center-recommendations-outside-of-azure